# How to link to nested static libraries with cmake

Tags: c, cmake, linker, static-libraries

I'm working on a project in C where I have an internal library and a main program. The internal library has a dependency on libjpeg-turbo, and the main has a dependency on the internal library. I'm learning cmake and trying to use the ExternalProject feature.

When I link everything as shared libraries (libjpeg-turbo and internal_lib), it works fine. But when I try to link them statically, the main fails with `undefined reference to jpeg_CreateDecompress` as if libjpeg was not linked properly.

Here is code for the **internal_lib**:

> `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(internal_lib LANGUAGES C)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(libjpeg-turbo
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git
    GIT_TAG 6c87537f60941f3c265c339fe60d1e31d2a42ccf # release v3.0.0
    GIT_SHALLOW ON
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(libjpeg-turbo BINARY_DIR)
set(LIBJPEG_BINARY_DIR "${BINARY_DIR}")
ExternalProject_Get_Property(libjpeg-turbo SOURCE_DIR)
set(LIBJPEG_SOURCE_DIR "${SOURCE_DIR}")

add_library(internal_lib STATIC lib.c)
# add_library(internal_lib SHARED lib.c)

target_include_directories(internal_lib PUBLIC "${LIBJPEG_BINARY_DIR}" "${LIBJPEG_SOURCE_DIR}" ./)
target_link_directories(internal_lib PUBLIC "${LIBJPEG_BINARY_DIR}")

target_link_libraries(internal_lib PUBLIC "${LIBJPEG_BINARY_DIR}/libjpeg.a")
# target_link_libraries(internal_lib PUBLIC jpeg)
```

> `lib.c`

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <jpeglib.h>
#include <lib.h>

int internal_func()
{
    struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
    jpeg_create_decompress(&cinfo);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is code for the **main** program

> `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

project(program LANGUAGES C)

include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(internal_lib_project
    SOURCE_DIR "../../internal_lib"
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(internal_lib_project SOURCE_DIR)
set(INTERNAL_LIB_SOURCE_DIR "${SOURCE_DIR}")
ExternalProject_Get_Property(internal_lib_project BINARY_DIR)
set(INTERNAL_LIB_BINARY_DIR "${BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(main main.c)
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC "${INTERNAL_LIB_SOURCE_DIR}")
target_link_directories(main PUBLIC "${INTERNAL_LIB_BINARY_DIR}")
target_link_libraries(main PUBLIC internal_lib)
```

> `main.c`

```c
#include <lib.h>

int main()
{
    internal_func();
    return 0;
}
```

I do not understand why libjpeg is not included in internal_lib when I link to the libjpeg.a ?

I tried to set `-DENABLE_SHARED=OFF -DENABLE_STATIC=ON` to make sure I get a static libjpeg lib.

If I manually add the path to `libjpeg.a` in `target_link_libraries(main, ...)` it works, but I think I shouldn't have to do that ? If it is necessary is there a way for cmake to do this for me ? I don't know how to access these 'internal' dependencies from the main.

Answer (score 1):

Static  libraries are nothing more than archives of object files. Linking with a static library is almost like linking with the individual object files. That means, if a static library depends on another library, then you need to link with both. The static libraries themselves have no information about its own dependencies.

With that said, CMake allows you to add dependencies to static library targets in the `CMakeLists.txt` file, and will then handle linking with those dependencies. That's what happens when you use the  [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command for the library target itself. You could also set [properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html) for dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on static libs I understand better. Is there a way to get these dependencies by using ExternalProject?